# How to properly upload file from vue to laravel?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, axios, controller

When I send a photo I get a 422 error from axios with message:

> The preview must be a file of type: jpg, jpeg, png, pdf.

But I sent the photo in the correct format. I don't really understand where the error is.

My vue component methods:

```
data() {
        return {
            name: '',
            description: '',
            preview: '',
        }
    },
    methods: {
        create() {
            this.projectStore.createProject(this.name, this.description, this.preview)
        },
        onFileChange(e) {
            let img = e.target.files[0]
            let reader = new FileReader()
            reader.readAsDataURL(img)
            this.preview = img
        },
    },
```

My store(Pinia) method:

```
async createProject(name, description, preview) {
            let formData = new FormData()
            formData.append('preview', preview)
            console.log(formData);
            axios.get('/sacntum/csrf-cookie').then(response => {
                axios.post('api/create', {
                    name: name,
                    description: description,
                    preview: formData,
                }, {
                    headers: {
                        'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
                    }
                })
                    .then(response => {
                        if (response.data.success) {
                            console.log(response)
                        } else {
                            console.log('response')
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.error(error)
                    })
            })
        },
```

My Controller in Laravel:

```
public function createProject(Request $request)
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            $attr = $request->validate([
                'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
                'description' => 'required|string|max:1000',
                'preview' => 'required|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,pdf|max:2048',
            ]);

            $generated_new_name = time() . '.' . $attr['preview']->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $request->preview->move(public_path('preview_images'), $generated_new_name);

            $project = Project::create([
                'name' => $attr['name'],
                'description' => $attr['description'],
                'preview' => $generated_new_name,
            ]);

            $success = true;
            $message = 'Project created successfully';
        } else {
            $success = false;
            $message = 'You are not logged yet';
        }

        $response = [
            'success' => $success,
            'message' => $message,
        ];

        return response()->json($response);
    }
```

I tried to make formdata in vue component and then pass to store but it didn't help

Comment: try slowly removing each validation rule to see which one is potentially it? e.g. is it 'max' (str length? seems a weird rule to apply to an image file). edit: actually, I've just realised this is a vue issue - laravel is very clear - the provided value for preview does not match the requested mime type.

Comment: @mikey yes i think problem in vue, maybe its because of formdata. It cannot be problem with laravel since its just simple validation

Comment: what do you see when you use dd($request->all()) in the first line of the authentication check?

Comment: @Nothingbutageek, I can see the data, including my review, which is a formdata object

Comment: @Nothingbutageek, if i try to return my $request->all() from controller to store using axios, in axios message i have such data object: 
`{
    "name": "asdf",
    "description": "asdf",
    "preview": "[object FormData]"
}`

Comment: Now the question is how to process my Formdata object into an appropriate format to pass to the controller so that the file can pass validation

Comment: I have added a comment under the post, this should help you with your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally i figured out was wrong. I changed this code in my createProject in my Store.js:

```
let formData = new FormData()
        formData.append('preview', preview)
        console.log(formData);
        axios.get('/sacntum/csrf-cookie').then(response => {
            axios.post('api/create', {
                name: name,
                description: description,
                preview: formData,
            }, {
                headers: {
                    'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
                }
            })
```

To this:

```
let formData = new FormData()
        formData.append('name', name)
        formData.append('description', description);
        formData.append('preview', preview)
        console.log(preview);
        axios.get('/sacntum/csrf-cookie').then(response => {
            axios.post('api/create', formData, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                }
            })
```

I passed the formdata object with the photo separately with the other parameters, although I should have put all the parameters in formdata.

Thanks everyone who tried to help. @Nothingbutageek I think it's not necessary to write custom rules for the photo unless you need some specific validation or specific error response, although if you need specific error response you can use form request validation.

Answer (score 0):

**Use the below code in the controller**

```
    $photo = $request->file('image');
    $imagename = time() . '.' . $photo->getClientOriginalExtension();        
    
    // Add Normal Image...
    $destinationPath = public_path('uploads');
    $photo->move($destinationPath, $imagename);

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r("Upload Successfully. Store File : laravel_code/public/uploads & laravel_code/public/uploads/thumbnail_images");
```

Comment: your solution may work, but in my case i need perform validaion like i did in the code. I guess it's not ther problem of laravel. More likely vue problem

Comment: if you get the file to the controller or request, you would handle rest with the laravel

Answer (score 0):

In order to validate a file on laravel request you will need to write a custom validation.
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#custom-validation-rules

The passes function should be something like this

```
public function passes($attribute, $value): bool
{
    $extension = strtolower($value->getClientOriginalExtension());

    return in_array($extension, ["jpg", "jpeg", "png", "pdf"]);
}
```

The function above only controls the mime types, you can add whichever validation you wish in this function